# How to use shadcn/ui Range Date Picker inside Form?

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js, react-hook-form, shadcnui

I have a problem with using The Range Date Picker inside the Form component. To be exact, I need an object to store the {from, to} values of the range, but using an object as a Form field value makes error messages not work. I just get undefined as an error message.

The current fix I'm using, is that I just modified the Form Message Component to render the errors a bit differently, but I think it's more of a hack than the proper way.

The code:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Title must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
  date: z.object({
    from: z.date(),
    to: z.date(),
  }),
});

function NewEventPage() {
  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      date: {},
    },
  });

  function onError(a) {
    console.log(a);
    /*
    title:
      message: "Title must be at least 2 characters."
      ref: {focus: ƒ, select: ƒ, setCustomValidity: ƒ, reportValidity: ƒ}
      type: "too_small"
    date:
      from: {message: 'Required', type: 'invalid_type', ref: undefined}
      to: {message: 'Required', type: 'invalid_type', ref: undefined}
    */
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}
        className="mx-auto mt-12 grid max-w-screen-lg grid-cols-2 gap-x-12 gap-y-8"
      >
        <h1 className="col-span-2 scroll-m-20 text-center text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight lg:text-5xl">
          Create A New event
        </h1>

        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="title"
          render={({ field }) => {
            return (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Event Title</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="The best title ever" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>Give a name for your event</FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            );
          }}
        />

        <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="date"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>Date</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <Popover>
              <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <Button
                  variant={"outline"}
                  className={cn(
                    "w-full justify-start text-left font-normal",
                    !field.value && "text-muted-foreground",
                  )}
                >
                  <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                  {field.value?.from ? (
                    field.value.to ? (
                      <>
                        {format(field.value.from, "LLL dd, y")} -{" "}
                        {format(field.value.to, "LLL dd, y")}
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      format(field.value.from, "LLL dd, y")
                    )
                  ) : (
                    <span>Pick a date</span>
                  )}
                </Button>
              </PopoverTrigger>
              <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
                <Calendar
                  initialFocus
                  mode="range"
                  defaultMonth={field.value?.from}
                  selected={field.value}
                  onSelect={field.onChange}
                  numberOfMonths={2}
                />
              </PopoverContent>
            </Popover>
          </FormControl>
          <FormDescription>
            Select the date for when the event will take place
          </FormDescription>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />

        <Button type="submit" className="col-span-2">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Title shows the error, but date shows undefined:
[image: Title shows the error, but date shows undefined]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give it a define Error message:

```
  const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Title must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
  date: z.object({
    from: z.date(),
    to: z.date(),
  }).refine(
      (data) => data.from > addDays(new Date(), -1),
      "Start date must be in the future"
    ),
});
```

and remove `date: {}` from DefaultValues which is causing undefined.

Write like this:

```js
function NewEventPage() {
  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it the following way:

```
const DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR = "Date is required.";

const formSchema = z.object({
   date: z.object({
       from: z.date().optional(),
       to: z.date().optional(),
   }, {required_error: DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR}).refine((date) => {
       return !!date.from;
   }, DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR),
   comment: z.string().min(1, {message: "A comment is required."}),
});
```

This is definitely not pretty. But this is the only configuration where I did not run into the following issue:

- When clicking on submit without having input a value in the range date picker, it showed undefined as an error, because it detected that *date.from* is undefined and therefore triggered the error for the entire *date* object. But the date object itself did not have an error, only the *date.from* inside of it. The error is apparent not propagated up to the date object. That is the reason why it showed the error undefined. That is why I put the *date.from* as optional, so it would never cause an error.
- Then I added the `refine((date) => {...})` to the *date object itself*. In there, it checks if date.from is undefined. If it is, the `DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR` text will be displayed in the UI. By doing it this way, you "lift" the error from *date.from* to the date object itself and it is displayed correctly.

**So why then the `{required_error: DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR}` too?**

This has the following reason:

- When having inserted a value in the date range picker and *then having removed it again*, for some reason, it triggers the `Required` error on the date object. If the `required_error` is not set, then the UI will just show *Required*. I personally disliked the two different error messages depending if you never isnerted a value or if inserted it and removed it again. That's why I added this, so these two errors are the same. If you don't care about that, you can leave it out.

I personally added the default values in the *useForm* so they are all there. But for me it also worked when not putting them in.

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        date: {
            from: undefined,
            to: undefined,
        },
        comment: ''
    },
});
```

You also need to change `selected` field in the Calender tag. This is due to the *date.from* field being optional. The selected field needs it to be definitely set. That's why I assured that through the `!` operator.

```
<Calendar
  initialFocus
  mode="range"
  defaultMonth={field.value.from}
  selected={{from: field.value.from!, to: field.value.to}}
  onSelect={field.onChange}
  numberOfMonths={1}
/>
```

This is my full code. Note, that the comment field is not implemented in the UI yet and has a dummy value in the defaults:

```
"use client"

import {Form, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {z} from "zod";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import {zodResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {Popover, PopoverContent, PopoverTrigger} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import {Button} from "@/components/ui/button";
import {cn} from "@/lib/utils";
import {format} from "date-fns";
import {CalendarIcon} from "lucide-react";
import {Calendar} from "@/components/ui/calendar";
import * as React from "react";

const DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR = "Date is required.";

const formSchema = z.object({
    date: z.object({
        from: z.date().optional(),
        to: z.date().optional(),
    }, {required_error: DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR}).refine((date) => {
        return !!date.from;
    }, DATE_REQUIRED_ERROR),
    comment: z.string().min(1, {message: "A comment is required."}),
});

export default function CommentSection() {
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        date: {
            from: undefined,
            to: undefined,
        },
        // TODO: remove this dummy value
        comment: "asdf"
    },
});

function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    console.log(values);
}

return (
    <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-5">
            <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name='date'
                render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                        <FormLabel>Date</FormLabel>
                        <Popover>
                            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                                <Button
                                    id="date"
                                    variant={"outline"}
                                    className={cn(
                                        "w-full justify-start text-left font-normal",
                                        !field.value.from && "text-muted-foreground"
                                    )}
                                >
                                    <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4"/>
                                    {field.value.from ? (
                                        field.value.to ? (
                                            <>
                                                {format(field.value.from, "LLL dd, y")} -{" "}
                                                {format(field.value.to, "LLL dd, y")}
                                            </>
                                        ) : (
                                            format(field.value.from, "LLL dd, y")
                                        )
                                    ) : (
                                        <span>Pick a date</span>
                                    )}
                                </Button>
                            </PopoverTrigger>
                            <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
                                <Calendar
                                    initialFocus
                                    mode="range"
                                    defaultMonth={field.value.from}
                                    selected={{from: field.value.from!, to: field.value.to}}
                                    onSelect={field.onChange}
                                    numberOfMonths={1}
                                />
                            </PopoverContent>
                        </Popover>
                        <FormDescription>
                            The date you want to add a comment for.
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage/>
                    </FormItem>
                )}
            />
            <Button type={"submit"}>Submit</Button>
        </form>
    </Form>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it the following way:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Title must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
 date: z
      .object(
        {
          from: z.date(),
          to: z.date().optional(),
        },
        { required_error: "Date is required." },
      )
      .refine((date) => {
        return !!date.to
      }, "End Date is required."),
});

function NewEventPage() {
  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
    },
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).